# sort array based on conditions using javascript sort function

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I want to sort an javascript array based on numbers but I wanted a specific group (e.g. Recommended) comes first and ascending, followed by other group that has no types.

Below are the divs, I wanted to sort in such a way that the Recommended comes first and in ascending order followed by other divs in ascending order.

[image]

Below code is sorting the divs with no **data-type** in ascending order correctly but the **Recommended** is not sorting in ascending order as expected.

```
var sortedDivs = $(".terminalpopular").toArray().sort(sorter);
console.log(sortedDivs); 

function sorter(a, b) {
    if(a.getAttribute('data-type') == 'Recommended'){
        if (parseFloat(a.getAttribute('data-amount')) < parseFloat(b.getAttribute('data-amount'))){
          return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else{
      if (parseFloat(a.getAttribute('data-amount')) > parseFloat(b.getAttribute('data-amount'))){
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    }
  }
```

Above code sorts the divs in such form as;

```
<div class="hotel-list listing-style3 hotel" id="list_view_listingpopular">
    <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="65.95" data-type="Recommended">
    </div>
    <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="94.95" data-type="Recommended">  </div>
    <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="70" data-type="Recommended">
    </div>
    <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="54.95" data-type="">
    </div>
    <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="67.99" data-type="">
    </div>
    <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="75" data-type="">
    </div>
    <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="78" data-type="">
    </div>
    <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="84.99" data-type="">
    </div>
    <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="84.99" data-type="">
    </div>
    </div>
```

As, it can be seen that divs without any **data-type** is sorted correctly but **Recommended** divs are not sorted in ascending order as expected.

Note: It does come in IF clause and condition does meet i.e. `(if(a.getAttribute('data-type') == 'Recommended'){})`. I have put console in IF and it does compare values.

Please, help. Thanks

Comment: Only return 0 if they are equal. At the two places where you return 0 it is not sure that both are equal, add another check

Comment: If you can share your HTML instead of just snapshot, it would help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks to type coercion in JS you can use a Boolean (like in a comparison) as a Number. And the same with the Strings. Since `-` is a numeric operation, the strings will be casted to Numbers, too.

So you can treat this like a simple numeric sort on two "properties".

```js
function sorter(a, b) {
    return (b.dataset.type === 'Recommended') - (a.dataset.type === 'Recommended') 
        || a.dataset.amount - b.dataset.amount;
}

var sortedDivs = $(".terminalpopular").toArray().sort(sorter);

console.log(sortedDivs)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hotel-list listing-style3 hotel" id="list_view_listingpopular">
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="65.95" data-type="Recommended">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="54.95">
  </div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="70" data-type="Recommended">
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="84.99">
  </div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="94.95" data-type="Recommended"> </div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="75">
  </div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="67.99">
  </div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="78">
  </div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="84.99">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. you are great. I have got idea from your answer and extend it to other types as well and working like a charm. Thanks mate.

Comment: I have an update. Can you suggest that how can I sort the array based on types in such way. i.e. Recommended have values of 84, 74, 64 and we have Featured type as well and having values of 78, 68, 88. Can we sort it in such form: 64 (recommended), 68 (featured), 74(recommended), 78 (featured), 84(recommended), 88 (featured) etc ?

Comment: @Owais If you want to interleave recommended and featured types, and make them all sticky, then you should go with an approach like [dev8080s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46292324/6567275). This would be unreasonable to do just with a sort-function; if it is even possible. Sort the items by amount, then group them by type *(recommended, featured, rest)*. Now you should have sorted groups. Interleave the recommended and featured Arrays, and then concat the rest to that Array.

Answer (score 2):

If elements of a type are to be ordered amongst themselves before the others, you should probably separate them in an array and sort them there, merging them wiht the rest of the sorted elements later.

Try this:

```
 var sortedDivs1 = $(".terminalpopular").toArray().filter(function(){
               return $(this).attr('data-type') == 'Recommended'
            }).sort(sorter);
 var sortedDivs2 = $(".terminalpopular").toArray().filter(function(){
               return $(this).attr('data-type') != 'Recommended'
            }).sort(sorter);
var sortedDivs = $.merge(sortedDivs1, sortedDivs2);
console.log(sortedDivs); 

function sorter(a, b) {

        return parseFloat(a.getAttribute('data-amount')) - 
               parseFloat(b.getAttribute('data-amount'));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return 0 only when both are equal.

Use this at both places where you compare the amount attribute:

```
return parseFloat(a.getAttribute('data-amount')) - parseFloat(b.getAttribute('data-amount'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can be done in just one sort, but with two, this is working for me...

```
var myList = $(".terminalpopular");

myList.sort(function(a, b){
    return $(a).data("amount")-$(b).data("amount");
}).sort(function(a, b){
    if ($(a).data("type") == "Recommended" && !$(b).data("type"))
        return -1;
    else if (!$(a).data("type") && $(b).data("type") == "Recommended")
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
});

$("#list_view_listingpopular").html(myList);
```

Here you have a fiddle... https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/c47Lfq8c/

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple logic:

- Create 4 flags, 2 for *element is recommended* and 2 for *amount value*
- Since recommended has higher precedence than amount, it should come first.
- If both are recommended, check for amount

```js
function sortList() {
  var list = $('.terminalpopular');
  var clone = list.clone();
  var recommended = 'Recommended'
  clone.sort(function(a, b) {
    var isARecommended = $(a).data('type') === recommended ? -10 : 0;
    var isBRecommended = $(b).data('type') === recommended ? -10 : 0;

    var amountA = Number($(a).data('amount'));
    var amountB = Number($(b).data('amount'));

    return isARecommended - isBRecommended || amountA - amountB;
  });
  list.parent().empty().append(clone)
}

// This is only for display purpose
function displayValue() {
  $('.terminalpopular').each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).text($(el).data('amount'));
    if ($(el).data('type')) {
      $(el).addClass('highlight')
    }
  })
}

displayValue();
sortList();
```

```css
.terminalpopular {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.highlight {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hotel-list listing-style3 hotel" id="list_view_listingpopular">
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="65.95" data-type="Recommended">
  </div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="94.95" data-type="Recommended"> </div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="70" data-type="Recommended">
  </div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="54.95" data-type="">
  </div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="67.99" data-type="">
  </div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="75" data-type="">
  </div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="78" data-type="">
  </div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="84.99" data-type="">
  </div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="84.99" data-type="">
  </div>
</div>
```